# Copy APK file in a folder?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a ListView with all the applications installed on the device. Is there a way that on click of the application copy its relative APK in a folder in the phone? Let me explain, for example, i Click the Browser application, copy its APK (Browser.apk) in the Example folder. So I Example / Browser.apk. This is my code for OnClick on Application, that for the moment uninstall the application, but I would replace it with the function of copy APK in a folder.

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

    Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packageName);
    Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
    startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}
```

Comment: Not possible (unless rooted) to prevent easy-mode apk sharing.

Comment: I do not have to share the APK but copy it to another folder.

Answer (score 1):

To get the .apk file of an application programatically you have to:

1. Get all installed applications
2. Get public source directory
3. Copy the file to the SDCard

**Note: No need to be rooted.**

The snipet code:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);

for (Object object : pkgAppsList) {

    ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
    File file =new File( info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);

    // Copy the .apk file to wherever
}
```

Comment: You can post me the code to copy the APK in a folder? Use my snippet please.

Comment: This site does not work that way :$ if you have a problem you say how you have tried to resolve it and from there maybe we help.